# select 4 from dual minus select 5 from dual

Tags: sql, oracle

select 4 from dual minus select 5 from dual; why this doesn't return -1 ? Can anyone comment over this, Thanks in advance.
The output is like below

```
------
4
---
4
```

column name is 4 and data also 4.

Comment: Return the rows from first select, `except` those from second select.

Answer (score 2):

`MINUS` does not do what you think. It is a set operator, ie it operates on set of rows, not on scalar values. It returns all rows in the first statement that are not returned by the second statement.

You probably want:

```
select 4 - 5 from dual
```